# Assigning a variable within a pipe and continuing?

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

```
hist(dat)
std_dev <- sd()
round(std_dev,3)
```

My professor wants us to put this in a single line of code using pipes, however, I'm having issues assigning `std_dev <- sd()` and continuing.

Attempts:

```
dat %T>% hist() %>% sd() %>% .->std_dev %>% round(.,3)
```

> Error in .(.) : could not find function "."

```
dat %T>% hist() %>% sd() %>% ~(.->std_dev) %>% round(,3)
```

Doesn't assign anything to std_dev.

```
dat %T>% hist() %>% sd() %>% =std_dev %>% round(,3)
```

unexpected =

```
dat %T>% hist() %>% sd() %>% ->std_dev %>% round(,3)
```

unexpected '->'

Comment: Thats quite an odd request from the professor, why copy the sd() function under a new name? was there any explanation?

Comment: It's just to teach us pipes I guess. (https://renkun-ken.github.io/pipeR-tutorial/Pipe-operator/Pipe-with-assignment.html) the method in this isn't working for me or I don't understand it and it's the only thing I can find to assign a variable and keep moving.

Comment: that link refers to a seperate package `pipeR` which is different to the standard pipes people use with `magrittr`. You've not specified any packages in your question directly, does your professor specify?

Comment: It'd be best if I stuck with magrittr, but once I install pipeR, it works with "dat %T>% hist() %>>% sd() %>>% (~ std_dev) %>>% round(,3)"

Comment: are you sure that is working as intended. What your initial chunk shows is quite different, you are copying the function sd(), that doesnt seem to be doing the copy for me.

Comment: The first 3 lines of code are confusing us. The second line just copies `sd` to a function with a new name. The third line makes no sense at all as it's trying to round a function, not a number. I think the answer from @derek-harding is what was intended, though I'd just omit the assignment to `std_dev`.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

dat %T>% hist() %>% sd() %>% round(.,3) -> std_dev

Don't do this in the real world, though. Not very readable.

Comment: This does not produce the same effect as the first code chunk at all, he seems to duplicate the sd() function, not assign the result to it.

Comment: It doesn't produce the same result as the first function, but I'm pretty sure the first function is broken. This works perfectly, thank you, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to produce the side effect you are after could be to use `assign`, its a bit more verbose but works as expected in your first chunk.

```
library(magrittr)
dat %T>%
  hist() %T>%
  {assign(x = "std_dev", value = sd, envir = .GlobalEnv)} %>%
  std_dev() %>%
  round(3)
```

Using the `%T>%` until the data needs to be manipulated. Additionally, making sure to assign to the appropriate environment with `assign`.

This also only uses pipes available in the magrittr package.

**Note:** this may need change as the initial code chunk you've provided is questionable - no data is passed into the `round()` function, but rather a function you assigned from the existing `sd()`.